# Date / Month conversion does not meet as expected

Tags: vba, excel

Can anyone clarify my doubt? see the below code.

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print Format(Now(), "mm") ' 1.
    Debug.Print Format(Now(), "mmm") ' 2.
    Debug.Print Format(Now(), "m") ' 3.
    Debug.Print Format(Now(), "dd#mm#yy") ' 4.
    Debug.Print Format(Now(), "dd*mm*yyyy") '5.
    Debug.Print Format(Now(), "dd*mm*yy") ' 6.
End Sub
```

Above code returns as follows

1. 05
2. May
3. 5
4. 02#05#16
5. 02516123
6. 025123

I want to know why the list 5 and 6 returns `02516123` and `025123` respectively.

why it does not returns as **02*05*2016** and **02*05*16**

Can any one explain why?

Comment: No idea what is happening here, but a workaround would be something like this: Replace(Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy"), "-", "*")

Comment: `*` is not defined as a character for a date format string.

Comment: @paul Ogilvie, Thanks. then it should not allow results rather it should throw error.

Answer (score 1):

In case **4**, Excel treats the **#** symbol as a valid field separator.

In case **5** and **6**, Excel treats the ***** symbol as a concatenation symbol.

Comment: excel treats * as concatenation symbol? can you please explain briefly?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a litteral `*`, you must escape the character:

```
Debug.Print Format(Now(), "dd\*mm\*yyyy")
```